# How to create autosuggest textbox in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i am new to the desktop application development. i want to know how to implement the autosuggest feature in a textbox using data from the databases and on the data selected i want to get the id of the selected data

i am familiar with the web development and we use hidden field to save the id is there anything like that in windows forms?

I know autocompletesource method but we cant get the id of the selected data in that is there any other way to do this? please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this : [Creating winforms AutoComplete TextBox using C# in Windows application](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html)