# textbox auto complete (Multi Line)

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I am making a auto suggestion / complete textbox in C#, i followed below link, but text box isnt showing the suggestions

[How to create autosuggest textbox in windows forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648476/how-to-create-autosuggest-textbox-in-windows-forms)

```
//-------- Get all distinct description -----------------------------
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(Queries.qry16, Connection);
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

//--------- Storing ------------------------------------
while (reader.Read())
{
    namesCollection.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
}

//----------- Close after use ---------------------------------------
reader.Close();

//----------- Set the auto suggestion in description box ------------
descriptionBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
descriptionBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
descriptionBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
```

Here is my code , it is in load function of winform. And the nameCollection initializtion is in constructor... kindly please help to make it working.

I am editing my post rather then creating new... I have tried the my own code in single line textbox and it worked. Now i want the same in multi line... For research i googled more then 2 days trying different codes (one with intelli sense) but it didnt worked as auto suggestion available in textbox. Can any one give me suggestion to code the whole procedure to multi line.. Thank you.

Comment: Have you made certain that `namesCollection` actually contains any entries when you assign it as the data source?

Comment: private AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection;                      this is what i am using for name collection

Comment: Actually i found the problem, it is textbox is multi line rather then single line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[AutoCompleteSource does not work on multiline TextBox controls.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx)

Wich means you need to make it from scratch:

I would make a ListBox to display the content of your autocomplete:

```
var listBox = new ListBox();
Controls.Add(listBox);
```

You need eventhandling on your textbox however this is a bit crude, so i would rewrite it to stop the keyupevent at some point:

```
private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var x = textBox.Left;
    var y = textBox.Top + textBox.Height;
    var width = textBox.Width + 20;
    const int height = 40;

    listBox.SetBounds(x, y, width, height );
    listBox.KeyDown += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;

    List<string> localList = list.Where(z => z.StartsWith(textBox.Text)).ToList();
    if(localList.Any() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
    {
        listBox.DataSource = localList;
        listBox.Show();
        listBox.Focus();

    }
}
```

Now all you need is a handler to set the text in your textBox:

```
 void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyValue == (decimal) Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox2.Text = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
            listBox.Hide();                
        }
    }
```

Put in null checks where appropriate

Comment: Forgot to mention that the list here is your custom autocomplete source. Which in this case is just a List<string>.

Comment: Thank you, i was unable to say thanks for all the answers because of my account suspension.

Comment: list and textBox2 is not defined

Comment: I added the "var" to init of list. 
As for textBox2 this is winforms so that resides in another file which seemed rather redundant to mention and has not been missed for 4 years.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a New Component class by 'Adding New Item'. and then write the code for that class and then add that component wherever required..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code as it works in my case:

```
  AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    namesCollection.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
                reader.Close();
    descriptionBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
descriptionBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;    
                descriptionBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
                con.Close();
```

Please check if the reader is getting the desired records..:)

Comment: Actually mine code worked after i change it into single line... Still i want to know how to use that for multi line

Comment: @GreatMajestics: READ THIS LINK..Hope this solves your curiosity.:=)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5839/DIY-Intellisense

Comment: I already check the following link. Also mentioned in my edit. But didnt got how to implement my own suggestion text box.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of confusion on the "auto-suggestion" since that is basically auto-complete without the permission from the user to "complete" the text. Nevertheless here are a couple of links you might find helpful:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

[Autocomplete functionality on a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518442/autocomplete-functionality-on-a-textarea)

[AutoComplete extender for multi-line Textbox](http://forums.asp.net/t/1577849.aspx/1)

Scroll down on link #2, a user suggested a jquery solution and compare with link #1. You may find a solution.

Third link is from asp forums, similar question like yours was also answered by a link. You might want to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Thismay help you solving problem ;
You can change table name. you can change the query to load listbox.

```
    ListBox lbox;
    private void IletisimBilgileriDoldur()
    {
        try
        {
            string strQuery= "Select adres From tblIletisimBilgileri Where adres <> '';";
            veri = new OleDbCommand(strQuery,strConn);
            veri.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            if (strConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) strConn.Open();
            oku = veri.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(oku);
            oku.Close();
            txtAdres.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();
            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0)
            {
                lbox = new ListBox();
                for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
                {
                    lbox.Items.Add(dt.Rows[count]["adres"].ToString());
                }
            }
            txtAdres.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            txtAdres.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            if (strConn.State == ConnectionState.Open) strConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (strConn.State == ConnectionState.Open) strConn.Close();
        }
    }

    private void txtAdres_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = txtAdres.Left;
        var y = txtAdres.Top + txtAdres.Height;
        var width = txtAdres.Width;
        const int height = 120;

        lbox.SetBounds(x, y, width, height);
        lbox.KeyDown += lbox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        lbox.DoubleClick += lbox_DoubleClick;
        gbxAdres.Controls.Add(lbox);
        lbox.BringToFront();
        lbox.Show();
        ActiveControl = txtAdres;
    }

    void lbox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAdres.Text = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
        lbox.Hide();
    }
```