# Auto Completion for Multiline Text Box or richtext box in C# framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am unable to implement the auto suggest functionality in MultiLine Text Box.
Please Help?

```
 public void autoComplete()
        {

        AutoCompleteStringCollection AutoItem = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        string s;           
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("E:/try/AutoSuggest.txt");
        while ((s = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

                AutoItem.Add(s);

        }


        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest; ;
         textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
         textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutoItem;           

    }
```

This is for Single line Text Box, want to  implement in Multiline?

Comment: `AutoCompleteSource` doesn't work with multiline textboxes so you'll have to create your own as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972761/textbox-auto-complete-multi-line) or, for RTB, see [this post](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/55750-c-tutorial-creating-a-auto-completing-richtextbox/)

Comment: What's the problem you're having with your code?

Comment: want to implement it for multiline rather than just single kline