# AutoComplete in Multiline TextBox C# 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Can anyone help me in implementing Multiline Text Box AutoSuggest.in C# 3,5

Please give me some links. Have tried many but none worked out.

or u can give autosuggestin richtextBox as autosuugest suggest doesnt work in multiline textbox

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972761/textbox-auto-complete-multi-line). From   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx, it seems that you cannot make a multiline auto complete text box using the built in functionality in .net. You must built it from scratch