# Creating autocomplete for multiline textbox problems

Tags: c#, listbox, c#-3.0

Alright so the images weren't working so here is the code itself

```
private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1 = new ListBox();
        Controls.Add(listBox1);


        var x = textBox1.Left;
        var y = textBox1.Top + textBox1.Height;
        var width = textBox1.Width + 20;
        const int height = 40;

        listBox1.SetBounds(x, y, width, height);
        listBox1.KeyDown += listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

        List<string> localList = list.Where(z => z.StartsWidth(textBox1.Text)).toList();
        if (localList.Any() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = localList;
            listBox1.Show();
            listBox1.Focus();
        }

    }

    void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == (decimal)Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
            listBox1.Hide();
        }
    }
```

I have run into some errors and was wondering if anyone could help me with them. I am using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972761/textbox-auto-complete-multi-line). Any help is appreciated.

*Current problems are:*

listBox1.KeyDown += **listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged**;

List localList = **list**.Where(z => z.StartsWidth(textBox1.Text)).toList();

My errors are highlighted in bold.

Comment: Am I only one who can't see the image?

Comment: The link to the image gives a blank white image, so the uploaded image is the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is? Is the code throwing an exception? Where is 'list' defined (the list that is your source for `localList` linq query)

Comment: the list (`list.where...`) you're trying to use is a global list of words you wish to predict and suggest.

Comment: I don't have list defined anywhere. Is there a way I can define list using an array?

Comment: `NameOfYourArray.ToList()` ?

Comment: When I change list to my array it throws an exception at z.StartsWidth

Comment: Figured out startswidth is a typo and should be StartsWith. Changed that and now it is bringing up another exception at toList() saying it doesn't contain a definition and no extension method

Comment: StartsWith is a method of string. You'll need to iterate over each element in your list and try StartsWith

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any method `listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged`. So change

```
listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
```

to

```
listBox_SelectedIndexChanged
```

and you have bolded out **List**. It has to be your list of some object, which you haven't shown us. Change the name.

**Note:** When you copy do change the names as they are defined in your code.

Comment: Did you mean do not change the names of copied code? Good catch on the method name.